# Adding new Entity generates negative id

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to add a new Container entity, but when I add the entity, I'm getting a negative `Id` being displayed in the resulting dataset. However, inside of my SQL database, I end up getting the correct next Id of the Container that was just inserted.

I've looked around, and I can see where this same issue occurs if you were to `Update` the entity before adding it - but I can't quite see anything related to the error occuring when you're first Adding the entity.

I'm literally just passing a new'ed up Container object, and adding it to the Containers DbSet on the ProductContext.

```
public class ProductService : IProductService 
    public ProductService(IProductContext productContext)
    {
        _productContext = productContext;
    }

    public Container CreateContainer(Container container, int currentUserId)
    {
        _productContext.Containers.Add(container);
        _productContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return container;
    }
}
```

However, when stepping through, I can see that I start off with a zero'd out Id...
[image: Creating Box 13 with an Id of 0]

And after the save is processed, the container has an `Id` of -2147482645.

[image]

But if I check the database, I end up with the correct next value after it's been saved. However, this value does not update on the entity, instead it stays as the -2147482645 value.

Here's my Container entity...

```
public class Container : BaseEntity
{
    public Container()
    {
        this.ChildContainers = new HashSet<Container>();
        this.InventoryItems = new HashSet<InventoryItem>();
    }

    public ICollection<Container> ChildContainers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<InventoryItem> InventoryItems { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public int? LocationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentContainerId ")]
    public Container ParentContainer { get; set; }

    public int? ParentContainerId { get; set; }
}
```

and the value of the BaseEntity class

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    protected virtual object Actual => this;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is BaseEntity other))
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;

        if (Actual.GetType() != other.Actual.GetType())
            return false;

        if (Id == 0 || other.Id == 0)
            return false;

        return Id == other.Id;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(BaseEntity a, BaseEntity b)
    {
        if (a is null && b is null)
            return true;

        if (a is null || b is null)
            return false;

        return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(BaseEntity a, BaseEntity b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Actual.GetType().ToString() + Id).GetHashCode();
    }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }

}
```

And the implementation of my SaveChangesAsync method - however, I don't believe this really could affect it, as the Id is getting updated before it hits this point.

```
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        var entries = ChangeTracker
            .Entries()
            .Where(e => e.Entity is BaseEntity && (
                    e.State == EntityState.Added
                    || e.State == EntityState.Modified));

        foreach (var entityEntry in entries)
        {
            ((BaseEntity)entityEntry.Entity).UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;

            if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                ((BaseEntity)entityEntry.Entity).CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }

        return await base.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

EDIT 1: SaveChanges syncronously

It was mentioned that the SaveChanges could affect it as I was running the asynchronous version of the method in a synchronous way. I don't believe this would be causing the error, as the Id is getting set/updated inside the Add method.

[image]

Comment: Don't call async method w/o awaiting it. If the method is synchronous, call `SaveChanges` and after that you'll have a correct Id. The negative values you see are temporary generated values before the entity is saved to the database and actual db generated value is retrieved.

Comment: I tried that as well, and I still get the same issue. The negative Id is coming on the Add, before I get to the SaveChangesAsync or SaveChanges call.

Comment: Of course it is coming. This is the temporary value I'm talking about. The real value is coming **after** `SaveChanges`. See docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations. May be you are confused what `Add` does - it just adds the entity to the cache, generates temp Id and marks it for insert. The actual database insert/update/delete happen in `SaveChanges`.

Comment: Wow, I'm dumb. Thanks much for explaining more in depth! That really did solve my issue.